# iText7 setting text size when adding SVG to PDF

Tags: c#, svg, itext7

I'm trying to convert an SVG string into an image.  I then add the image to the PDF document.  The reason I want to convert SVG to an Image is to have the ability to size and rotate the image on the page.  But when the image is added to the PDF the text on the image is too big and all my alignments are wrong.

I tried to add the image to the PDF without doing any conversion from SVG, and the same issue appears.

Here is the code that I'm using in my PDFGeneration class:

```
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("C:/test.pdf"));
        PageSize ps = PageSize.A4;  //.Rotate();
        pdf.AddNewPage(ps);
        FontProvider provider = new FontProvider();            

        provider.AddFont(FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Poppins-Regular.otf"));
        SvgConverterProperties props = new SvgConverterProperties();
        props.SetCharset("Windows-1252");
        props.SetFontProvider(provider);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(svg);
        Document document = new Document(pdf, ps);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            Image image = SvgConverter.ConvertToImage(ms, pdf, props);

            float width = image.GetXObject().GetWidth();
            float widthContainer = ps.GetWidth();
            float heightContainer = ps.GetHeight();
            float imageLlx = 0;
            float imageLly = 0;

            image.SetFixedPosition(imageLlx, imageLly);                
            image.ScaleToFit(widthContainer, heightContainer - imageLly);
            document.Add(image);
        }
```

Here is my SVG string

```
       String svg = "<svg width=\"852px\" height=\"392px\" viewBox=\"0 0 
       852 392\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" 
       xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" style=\"width: 852px; 
       height: 392px;\">" + 
            "<g transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)\" clip-path=\"url(#mainClip723)\"><g transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 191, 71)\"><g transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -190, 20)\">" +
            "<rect x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"180\" height=\"35\" fill=\"transparent\" stroke=\"none\" transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)\"/>" +
            "<path d=\"M 5,0 L 175,0 C 177.23857625084602,0 180,2.761423749153968 180,5 L 180,30 C 180,32.23857625084603 177.23857625084602,35 175,35 L 5,35 C 2.761423749153968" +
            ",35 0,32.23857625084603 0,30 L 0,5 C 0,2.761423749153968 2.761423749153968,0 5,0 z\" fill=\"transparent\" stroke=\"none\" transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)\"/>" +
            "<g transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)\"><text x=\"0\" y=\"8.9340087890625\" style=\"font: 8px sans-serif\" text-anchor=\"start\" fill=\"black\" stroke=\"none\" transform=" +
            "\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 20.610839843749993, 5.587988281249999)\">Customer Success Manager</text><text x=\"0\" y=\"20.846020507812497\" style=\"font: 8px sans-serif\"" +
            "text-anchor=\"start\" fill=\"black\" stroke=\"none\" transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 20.610839843749993, 5.587988281249999)\">(CSM)</text></g></g><g transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)\">" +
            "<rect x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"130\" height=\"80\" fill=\"transparent\" stroke=\"none\" transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)\"/>" +
            "<path d=\"M 5,0 L 124,0 C 126.23857625084604,0 129,2.761423749153968 129,5 L 129,74 C 129,76.23857625084604 126.23857625084604,79 124,79 L 5,79 C 2.761423749153968,79 0,76.23857625084604 0,74 L 0,5 C 0,2.761423749153968 2.761423749153968,0 5,0 z\"" +
            "fill=\"white\" stroke=\"none\" transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5)\"/><path d=\"M 5,0 L 124,0 C 126.23857625084604,0 129,2.761423749153968 129,5 L 129,74 C 129,76.23857625084604 126.23857625084604,79 124,79 L 5,79 C 2.761423749153968,79 0,76.23857625084604 0,74 L 0,5 C 0,2.761423749153968 2.761423749153968,0 5,0 z\"" +
            "fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"1\" stroke-linecap=\"butt\" stroke-linejoin=\"miter\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5)\"/>" +
            "<g transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)\"><text x=\"0\" y=\"8.9340087890625\" style=\"font: 8px sans-serif\" text-anchor=\"start\" fill=\"grey\" stroke=\"none\" " +
            "transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 10.585449218750005, 22.13198242187501)\">Identify mismatch by</text><text x=\"0\" y=\"20.846020507812497\" style=\"font: 8px sans-serif\" " +
            "text-anchor=\"start\" fill=\"grey\" stroke=\"none\" transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 10.585449218750005, 22.13198242187501)\">" + 
            "comparing Closings to</text><text x=\"0\" y=\"32.7580322265625\" style=\"font: 8px sans-serif\" text-anchor=\"start\" fill=\"grey\" stroke=\"none\" " +
            "transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 10.585449218750005, 22.13198242187501)\">data captured in Pure</text></g></g><g transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)\">" +
            "<rect x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"130\" height=\"16\" fill=\"transparent\" stroke=\"none\" transform=\"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)\"/></svg>";
```

I'm expecting the text to fit nicely in the box once it's drawn on the PDF document.  At the moment the text is not displayed within the box drawn and I think it could be solved by decreasing the text size to 8px?

I can change the font, but I cannot change the font size and the svg convert does not seem to take the font size from the svg string.

Comment: SVG is XML string and not a picture.  The string posted is showing the properties of a picture box with a link to a file url(#mainClip723).  To display the picture you would need do some conversion.

Comment: I was able to find a work around by replacing the Font text inside the SVG sting with Font-Size:  svg.Replace("style=\"font: 11px sans-serif\"", "font-size=\"9.5\"")